# @media screen and (max-width:800px) not working, looked all over the internet

Tags: html, css

Please, someone, help me... In my recent project this function worked perfectly, but now it doesn't... CSS rules @media screen and (max-width:800px) just don't work. I've looked all over the Internet and wasn't able to find the solution, can someone help me, please?

```css
html body{
    background-color: #fafafa;
    height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    html body{background-color:#fff;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Google Roboto Fonts -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,300italic,300,100italic,100,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <!-- My code -->
      
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "don't work" and "not working" mean? Replace the imprecise wording with a descriptive alternative.

Comment: You 2 colors are almost the same, which may have confused you... But the css works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/jqaf2x26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem in your snippet is that you haven't included jQuery. Bootstrap needs jQuery in order to perform.

I've included jQuery and just for debugging purpose, I've reduced `max-width` to `150 px` and it's now working fine.

> TIP: Open debug window in chrome (rightclick > Inspect or press F12) and when you'll reisize your window, the width will be shown at the top.

```css
html body{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 150px) {
    html body{background-color:#000;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Google Roboto Fonts -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,300italic,300,100italic,100,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <!-- My code -->
      
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turns out I just used old jQuery... Thanks!